# Import e Export não funciona mesmo com type="module"

Tags: javascript, import, módulo-ecmascript, export

Eu tenho um arquivo JavaScript chamado "redirect.js", no qual possui apenas duas funções semelhantes, que servem apenas para redirecionar para uma página específica, "redirect.js", contendo o seguinte código:

```
export function redirectToCorrectPage() {
  window.location.href = "right-answer.html";
}

export function redirectToIncorrectPage() {
  window.location.href = "wrong-answer.html";
}
```

Existem outros 3 Scripts que estou tentando importar essas funções, porém sem sucesso. O script 'redirect' está na mesma pasta que estes. Então, estou tentando importar da seguinte forma:

```
import { redirectToCorrectPage, redirectToIncorrectPage } from './redirect.js'
```

Estou tendo dois tipos de erros:

1. javascript - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Nas minhas páginas HTML, que estão direcionando para estes scripts, todas estão com " script type='module' "

Enfim, a minha dúvida é: Qual a melhor forma de fazer a importação dessas funções, e porquê o jeito que eu fiz não está funcionando.

Agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118650/discussion-on-question-by-pivian-import-e-export-nao-funciona-mesmo-com-typemo)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Quando você você deseja usar funções de arquivos javascripts diferentes no html, você precisa importá-los com o cuidado da prioridade

Por exemplo:

**redirect.js**

```
 const redirectToCorrectPage = () => {
  window.location.href = "right-answer.html";
}

const function redirectToIncorrectPage = () => {
  window.location.href = "wrong-answer.html";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <script src="redirect.js"></script>
      <script>
          redirectToCorrectPage()
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

O import e export são para serem usados em projetos nodejs como módulos ou requires